# iOS. Measure time in setKeepAliveTimeout:handler: while waiting for server response

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, multithreading, voip

I am developing a VoIP app. When my app is in background I need to check if the server is still there. So I am trying to use **setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:** to make polls to server while app is in background.

The question is: how to ensure that I receive response or timeout within 5 seconds after I have sent poll message to server? If I don't receive response/timeout within 5 seconds the next opportunity to know that server is dead is only after **keepAliveTimeout** time which is not that good.

As I understand I can't setup NSTimer in **setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:** since we are in background (and NSTimer relies on run loop).

I see other possibility which is: make while loop and check for the current time in it. Although I would like to avoid making busy loops.

Could you please suggest me how can I achieve needed behaviour?

Comment: why do you need to check your server is alive or dead when you app is in background and not doing anything for user?

Comment: In order to decrease socket connection uncertainty time. As I was told (maybe it is wrong) with some specific conditions it may take more than 30 minutes for socket to fail so all this time I will be thinking that I am connected and will not try to reconnect and do other app specific logic.